# Instantiating primitive store types in EF

Tags: entity-framework

Every Entity Framework provider contains a DbProviderManifest component that has the following method:

> public abstract ReadOnlyCollection GetStoreTypes();

This method is used to return all the database specific data types. For instance, MSSQL provider returns SqlServer.int, SqlServer.decimal, SqlServer.varchar... etc.

The returning collection contains PrimitiveType objects that store various information (including namespace and name) about the data types.

DbProviderManifest class are typically implemented by deriving from the DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest base class. It implements the mentioned method by parsing the data types from an [xml file](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/Resources/System/Data/SqlClient/System.Data.Resources.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.ProviderManifest.xml).

Unfortunately I haven't found any other way to implement this method properly, because the PrimitiveType class does not provide any pubic constructor or factory method that is capable of setting the namespace and name of data types. Is it possible to implement the DbProviderManifest class by pure code without the xml?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use reflection. PrimitiveType has internal constructor which accepts type name and namespace:

```
internal PrimitiveType(string name, string namespaceName, DataSpace dataSpace, PrimitiveType baseType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
```

WIth reflection you can get this constructor and create PrimitiveType by invoking it:

```
var type = typeof(PrimitiveType);
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
Binder binder = null;
var types = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(DataSpace), typeof(PrimitiveType), typeof(DbProviderManifest) };
ParameterModifier[] modifiers = null;

var constructor = type.GetConstructor(flags, binder, types, modifiers);
```

To create new PrimitiveType invoke this constructor and pass array of parameters to it:

```
object[] parameters = { "name", "namespace", ... };
PrimitiveType result = (PrimitiveType)constructor.Invoke(parameters);
```

Comment: This is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you will analyze usages of this internal constructor in `System.Data.Metadata.Edm` assembly, you will find that reflection is something you can't avoid